# How to use a generic HostBuilder in a UWP application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, uwp

In my WPF applications I use a generic HostBuilder in this way:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public App()
    {
        _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services => { ConfigureServices(services); })
            .Build();
    }
        
    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        // Add all services, viewmodels, etc..
    }

    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        await _host.StartAsync();
    }

    protected async override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        using(_host)
        {
            await _host.StopAsync();
        }
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

And in a UWP application:

```cs
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services => { ConfigureServices(services); })
            .Build();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add all services, viewmodels, etc..
    }

    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _host.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

**The question:**

Where/when should I stop the service?

```cs
using(_host)
{
    await _host.StopAsync();
}
```

Comment: Is the code here working for you? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @DavidG The problem is that UWP has not OnExit event or I'm not able to find it.

Comment: @McNets, does it really matter if you stop the host?  If the user exits the app, everything is gone anyway.

Comment: Could could create a service scope, and dispose that on `Application.Suspending` to release memory? But otherwise your process will just be terminated at some point.

Answer (score 1):

> Where/when should I stop the service?

You need to know UWP  [life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle), and [`OnSuspending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending?view=winrt-22000) meet your scenario, it will be invoked when the user switches to another app or to the desktop, base on the the life cycle, it also be invoked when your close app.

So, if your builder need to stop when app turn into suspend state, you could use above event.

And if you only want to stop the build when app close, please use [`CloseRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested?view=winrt-22000) event

```
 SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += (s, p)=>{ 
    // stop host here              
};
```

Please note for use this event, you need to add confirmAppClose capability to your app manifest file.

`xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">`

```
<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
```

**Update**

Derive from the document, the Host class looks only apply to .NET Platform Extensions, it does not coantain uwp.

Comment: Then should I start it again OnResume?

Comment: Sure, you could re-start it.

Comment: Is there a specific life cycle for the new WinUI3 apps?

Comment: new winui3 app is different with UWP, it more like general desktop app. please refer to document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/applifecycle)

Comment: It returns an unhandled exception, no matter where I Build it, Constructor, OnLaunched. Maybe it cannot be used with UWP apps.

Comment: I checked the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), it looks only apply to .NET Platform Extensions, it does not coantain uwp.

Comment: Yes this doesn't seem to work as the CreateDefaultBuilder injects EventLog logging by default and this is not supported by UWP. You can trey this instead: var builder = new HostBuilder();
                var host = builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>